# SSH ProxyCommand using aws SSM session manager and bash script with select command

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, ssh, aws-ssm

In my company when we SSH to our AWS EC2 instances we are required to use the aws CLI session-manager plugin for auth. Using this SSH config snippet works:

```
Host my-aws-host
    ProxyCommand bash -c "aws ssm start-session --target 'i-0abc123def456hij' \
        --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=22' \
        --region us-west-1 --profile MAIN"
```

However, when the EC2 instance is relaunched, which happens semi-regularly, the 'target' instance ID changes. When this happens, all users need to update their SSH config with the new ID. We don't have any sort of DNS that resolves these instances to a static hostname unfortunately, and so would need to somehow publish the new instance ID to all interested users.

So instead I wrote a bash script (`ssh_proxy_command.sh`) that first queries our AWS account to grab the current instance ID based on a known tag value, and use that for the target - here's a cut-down version:

```
#!/bin/bash

INSTANCE_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-west-1 \
        --filters Name=tag:Name,Values=my-server-nametag* \
        --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Instance:InstanceId}" --output text)

aws ssm start-session --target $INSTANCE_ID --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=22' --region us-west-1 --profile MAIN
```

Now the SSH config looks like

```
Host my-aws-host
    ProxyCommand bash -c "/path/to/my/ssh_proxy_command.sh %h"
```

This has been working fine. However, we have just started running multiple instances built from the same base image (AMI), and which use the same tags, etc. so the given describe-instances query now returns multiple instance IDs. So I tried wrapping the output returned by the query in a bash `select` loop, thinking I could offer the user a list of instance IDs and let them choose the one they want. This works when running the script directly, but not when it's used as the ProxyCommand. In the latter case when it reaches the `select` statement it prints out the options as expected, but doesn't wait for the user input - it just continues straight to the end of the script with an empty $INSTANCE_ID variable, which makes the `aws ssm` command fail.

I'm guessing this is a side-effect of the way SSH runs its ProxyCommands — from the `ssh_config` man page:

> [the proxy command] is executed using the user's shell ‘exec’ directive [...]

I'm hoping I can find a way around this problem while still using SSH config and ProxyCommand, rather than resorting to a complete stand-alone wrapper around the `ssh` executable and requiring everyone use that. Any suggestions gratefully accepted...

Comment: This seems less about programming and more about server admin? Should this be on the https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue trying to achieve exactly what you're trying to do here.

I solved by writing and reading to/from `tty` as it seems the only stream available in the spawned `exec` command is `/dev/stderr` (`select` command outputs to `stderr`). Following, the solution I adopted:

**~/.ssh/config**:

```
ProxyCommand sh ~/ssm-node-selection.sh <PROFILE>
```

**~/ssm-node-selection.sh**:

```bash
PROFILE=$1
TTY="/dev/tty$(ps ax | grep "^$$" | awk '{ print $2 }')"

EC2_INSTANCE_IDS=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --profile $PROFILE --query "Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId" --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=<INSTANCE_NAME>" | jq '. | join(" ")' | tr -d '"')
echo $EC2_INSTANCE_IDS > $TTY
echo "Choose an instance: " > $TTY
read INSTANCE_ID < $TTY

aws ec2-instance-connect send-ssh-public-key --profile $PROFILE --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --instance-os-user <USER> --ssh-public-key file://<PUBLIC_KEY> && aws ssm start-session --target $INSTANCE_ID  --profile $PROFILE --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan - this approach worked great in my situation, too. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
host my-aws-host
    ProxyCommand aws ssm start-session --target $(aws ec2 describe-instances --filter "Name=tag:Name,Values=%h" --query "Reservations[].Instances[?State.Name == 'running'].InstanceId[]" --output text) --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters portNumber=%p
```

The above will dynamically filter for your target-id based on host name (%h) provided so you can login using `ssh my-aws-host`. I personally have a prefix for all my machines in AWS so I ssh config is as follows:

```
host your-custom-prefix-*
    ProxyCommand aws ssm start-session --target $(aws ec2 describe-instances --filter "Name=tag:Name,Values=%h" --query "Reservations[].Instances[?State.Name == 'running'].InstanceId[]" --output text) --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters portNumber=%p
```

This works only when the name of your machines in AWS match the host name provided.